# Django not reading my HTML with CSS

Tags: html, css, django, python-3.x, web

I'm not a web developer but however, I'm in a project where we want to deploy a Django web app based in HTML and CSS front end. We have deployed an HTML code that looks like :

[image]

Unfortunately, when we deploy this in a login template for Django the fancy model is screwed up we get:

`Check out my code here:` https://jsfiddle.net/Andres/hmpbkc9n/#

[image]

Workaround:

I have just to add the file .css into the path `project\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static` and then I run the command:

```
 python manage.py findstatic css/login.css --verbosity 2
```

and I got:

[image]

However, it's not working yet.

Comment: perform `collectstatic` command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

Comment: The browser cannot find your CSS file. Read more about how to configure static assets as @SachiTekina linked above.

Comment: I have just to add the file .css into the path project\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static and then I run the command python manage.py findstatic css/login.css --verbosity 2 and I got: Found 'css/login.css' here:
  C:\Users\Dev\Envs\englishschool\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\css\login.css I doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static files such as CSS, JS, and images should be placed accordingly based on the STATIC setting in your [`settings.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) then perform a [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) command.